# Creating entity searchs by properties values

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

guys!
I'm trying to create a deep search for my entities. That's the idea: find some record using the entity by example.
NHibernate provides an ID search for us.

```
Entity entity = Session.Get<Entity>(id);
```

But I need to verify if some entity exists even ID is empty. Something like:

```
Entity search = new Entity("Full name from some record");
Entity entity = Session.Get<Entity>(search);
if (entity == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("This record don't exists.");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("This record exists!");
}
```

I want to search some entity into the database and returns a boolean value. TRUE if the record exists, FALSE if not. Is there something like this already done? If don't, do you have any idea how to implement this situation?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at this as a starting point:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-examples